# How to input block of text next to Font Awesome icon in CSS?

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

My problem is every time I put text next to the icon it either:

a) wraps under the image

b) doesn't show up on one line unless I specify the width

c) or if it shows up as a block, it does so above or below the icon instead of right next to it.

Here's the code:

```css
.fa-stack {
    font-size: 50px;
    margin-top: 30px;
}
.fa-square {
    color: #AA2200;
}
.q {
    color:white;
}
.boxtext2 {
    font-family: 'Raleway',sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 50px;
    margin-left: 200px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.fa-stack-1x {
background: gray;
}
```

```html
<div id ="container">
    <span class="fa-stack">
        <span class="fa fa-square fa-stack-2x"></span>
        <span class="fa fa-stack-1x q"><strong>Q</strong></span>
        <div class="boxtext2">
                texttextextexetexteafafaflegajf;lea
        </div> 
    </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATED

```
For responsive you need to add media query for custom class or id. Here is     
your AND Here is the zip for your help 
[https://www.dropbox.com/s/9mdybtoq4ruc3uu/demo.zip?dl=0][1]
//Code
  <body>
  <div class= "container-fluid">
   <div class= "row-fluid">
    <div class= "list">
     <span class="fa fa-stack">
          <i class="fa fa-square fa-stack-2x"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-stack-1x"><strong>Q</strong></i>
     </span>
    <span class="text"> test test test test echo echo echo </span>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>

</body> 
//style 
<style type="text/css">

  body{
   margin:15px ;
   }
  .list{
   list-style: none;
   display:inline-flex;
   }
  .text{
  font-size:2.5em;
  display:inline-flex;
  padding-top: 8.5%;
  padding-left: 20px;
  }
 .fa-stack-1x{
  background: gray;
  color: White;
  }
 .fa-stack {
  font-size: 50px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  }

 @media only screen and  (min-width:500px) and  (max-width:767px) and 
  (orientation : portrait){
  .text{font-size:19px; padding-top: 12.5%;}
  .fa-stack{font-size: 20px;  margin-top: 30px;}
  }
 @media only screen and  (min-width:500px) and (max-width:767px) and  
 (orientation : landscape){
  .text{font-size:19px; padding-top: 11.5%;}
  .fa-stack{font-size: 20px;  margin-top: 30px;}
  }
 @media only screen and (min-width:320px) and  (max-width:499px) and 
  (orientation : portrait){
  .text{font-size:16px; padding-top: 13.5%;}
  .fa-stack{font-size: 17px;  margin-top: 30px;}
  }
    @media only screen and (min-width:348px) and  (max-width:499px) and 
   (orientation : landscape){
   .text{font-size:16px; padding-top: 12.5%;}
   .fa-stack{font-size: 17px;  margin-top: 30px;}
   }
    @media only screen and (min-width:320px) and  (max-width:347px) and   

  (orientation : portrait){
     .text{font-size:14px; padding-top: 13.5%;}
    .fa-stack{font-size: 15px;  margin-top: 30px;}
    }
    @media only screen and (min-width:320px) and  (max-width:347px) and     
  (orientation : landscape){
   .text{font-size:14px; padding-top: 12.5%;}
  .fa-stack{font-size: 15px;  margin-top: 30px;}
   }

</style>
```

Happy coding :)

Comment: Thanks I didn't know that. Still it doesn't give me what I want.

Comment: you can share with me. What do you actually want ??  maybe I can help you

Comment: I want the text and the icon side by side without the text wrapping under the image when resided

Comment: which icon and what is the text ? which frame-work you use ? and what do you mean by resided ?? responsive ?

Comment: The icon is in the html. It's a custom stack icon. Text doesn't matter. It's just CSS. Yeah I meant responsive.

Comment: then you have to use media query for responsive .. if you set .fa class to new width or height

Comment: maybe you want like this. Fully responsive [https://www.dropbox.com/s/9mdybtoq4ruc3uu/demo.zip?dl=0] 
Down Load the zip you will get your css and html file
also edit your code with mine.

Comment: Thanks a lot my man. You know how I can stop the Q from moving as the window resizes?

Comment: do you really need    <i class="fa fa-square fa-stack-2x"></i> 
you just need the grey square box which contain the 'Q' inside right ?

Comment: I want a rounded square with the icon Q in the middle.

Comment: u can use css class border-radius. If you told me before you get that one

Comment: but if you fixed that square box with out change then you have to small size text beside when device width change. [https://www.dropbox.com/s/frljvtvq40wegxo/demo_2.zip?dl=0]

and learn css tricks. Happy Coding :)  good luck

Comment: Sorry for the last link maybe you want this [https://www.dropbox.com/s/ezird886yt4cf7x/demo_2.zip?dl=0]
enjoy happy coding 12 custom fa square box added.

Comment: Thanks for trying.

Comment: Please dnt say that you dont have the right answer yet :(

Comment: Not a big deal. Just wanted to know if there was a way to stop the Q from moving.

Comment: I think the last drop box code can't resize on screen size difference. And ofcourse there is way..

Comment: You don't know or you don't want to tell me?

Comment: did you check the last  [dropbox.com/s/ezird886yt4cf7x/demo_2.zip?dl=0] 
one

Answer (score 4):

Take another close look at the selectors for the rules you're trying to declare. You'll notice that `.boxtext2` is being used instead of `#boxtext2`.

```css
.fa-stack {
font-size: 50px;
margin-top: 30px;
}
.fa-square {
color: #AA2200;
}
.q {
color:white;
}
#boxtext2 {
font-family: 'Raleway',sans-serif;
font-size: 30px;
line-height: 50px;
margin-left: 200px;
display: inline-block;
}

.fa-stack-1x {
    background: gray;
}
```

```html
<div id ="container">
    <span class="fa-stack">
       <span class="fa fa-square fa-stack-2x"></span>
       <span class="fa fa-stack-1x q"><strong>Q</strong></span>
       <div id="boxtext2">
                texttextextexetexteafafaflegajf;lea
       </div> 
    </span>
</div>
```